# Apply a perspective transform with a hover animation to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

This looks like an easy one imo but I am missing something as I cant get it to run.

I want to use transform with the `perspective()` and `rotateY()` functions to create a perspective for the element. Then use a transition to update the transform attribute's value on hover. And change the `rotateY()` value to negative to mirror the perspective effect from left to right.
The [Codepen is here](https://codepen.io/krakruhahah/pen/VwXWywR) working and I am creating it in React .

`My App.tsx that is not working`

I declared all styles and apply them inline.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';

const styles = {
    imageCard: {
        display: ' inline-block',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
        margin: '1rem',
        width: '240px',
        height: '320px',
        padding: '8px',
        borderRadius: '1rem',
        background: 'url(https://picsum.photos/id/1049/240/320)',
        boxShadow: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 25px 50px -12px',
    },

    perspectiveLeft: {
        transform: 'perspective(1500px) rotateY(15deg)',
        transition: 'transform 1s ease 0s',
    },

    'perspectiveLeft:hover': {
        transform: 'perspective(3000px) rotateY(5deg)',
    },

    perspectiveRight: {
        transform: 'perspective(1500px) rotateY(-15deg)',
        transition: 'transform 1s ease 0s',
    },

    'perspectiveRight:hover': {
        transform: 'perspective(3000px) rotateY(-5deg)',
    },
};

function Perspective() {
    return (
        <Box styles={styles.imageCard}>
            <Box style={styles.perspectiveLeft}></Box>
            <Box style={styles.perspectiveRight}></Box>
        </Box>
    );
}

export { Perspective };
```

Comment: So you want to flip the entire card to the opposite side with the image mirrored on the opposing face or you want the card to just wiggle a bit and for the image to flip it's perspective horizontally?

If you can mock up in photoshop like a before and after of the effect you want to achieve that'd be a help.

Comment: Please upload a sandbox code of your react app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do these styles in React, but one option that **won't** work is inline styles because you can't control the `:hover` styles using inline styles.

One option is to use CSS classes just like in your code pen. The only thing you need to change for React is `class=...` becomes `className=...`:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      <div className="image-card perspective-left"></div>
      <div className="image-card perspective-right"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit perspective cards using CSS classes]

---

Since you were trying to leverage MUI's `Box`, I'm guessing you might be trying to incorporate this in a project using MUI and perhaps you want to use CSS-in-JS approaches rather than global CSS class names. Below is an example using MUI's `styled` API. This would also look nearly identical using Emotion's `styled` API which MUI's implementation delegates to.

```
import React from "react";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const ImageCard = styled("div")`
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 240px;
  height: 320px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1049/240/320");
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 25px 50px -12px;
`;
const ImageCardLeft = styled(ImageCard)`
  transform: perspective(1500px) rotateY(15deg);
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
  &:hover {
    transform: perspective(3000px) rotateY(5deg);
  }
`;
const ImageCardRight = styled(ImageCard)`
  transform: perspective(1500px) rotateY(-15deg);
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
  &:hover {
    transform: perspective(3000px) rotateY(-5deg);
  }
`;

export default function Perspective() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ImageCardLeft />
      <ImageCardRight />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit perspective cards]

Comment: Yes the  CSS-in-JS approach is perfect and that what I was thinking about, thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Use this animation

```
npm i react-parallax-tilt
```